# Show link based on query result

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to show a link if there are results from query. I get an error when the table is empty. Thanks in advance!

The html:

```
...
<div class="notification">
            <header><h3>Notification</h3></header>
            @if(Auth::user()->friends()->where(['status', 'received'])->first())
                <a href="" class="">You have a new request!</a>
                @endif
        </div>
...
```

The error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'
 (SQL: select * from `friends` where `friends`.`user_id` = 2 and `friends`.`user_id` is not null and (`0` = status and `1` = received) limit 1)
```

At the beginning the table is empty unless the user saves some information in the table. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The query is okay, except the `where` clause, you should not pass an array there like that, so try replacing the condition with this:

```
@if(Auth::user()->friends()->where('status', 'received')->first())
```

`first` returns **null** if not found which is `false` and it will work okay.

And as a suggestion I wouldn't put the query in the view, I would pass it from the controller better. So you can store into a variable for example:

```
$newFriends = Auth::user()->friends()->where('status', 'received')->first();

return view('your_view_name', compact('newFriends'));
```

Then in the view

```
@if($newFriends)
...
@endif
```

Comment: It's fine to pass as an array. Check the documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses. Good point about the variable, but it won't change the outcome.

Comment: Is it really fine to pass an array as he has? He passed an array of items, for which does not have any values. And as the documentation states there is an array of arrays each item array contains a column, an equation and a value.

Comment: The operator is assumed to be `=` if it's not specified. Maybe that's not the case in an array? I can't test right now but I'd expect it to work the same either way.

Comment: You can see from the error above, that it tries to do `0=status` and `1=received` and what he tries to do is `status=received` and for that he just needs to remove the array, as he uses just one column for the where clause, not multiple columns.

Comment: Yes, I didn't see the full query in the error message. I guess operator isn't assumed within an array, only outside.

Comment: I think it will be, but he will need to do `[['status', 'received']]` an item of an array, because now it uses the index as a column name, instead the first item. But in any case no need for an array when single comparison is done.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the where clause in the query, you are passing an array but not using the array => operator between the index and the value, so php will think that both `status` and `received` are array values and will not use `status` as the index, for more details [php arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php).

so to solve this you can use where clause without array, since you are checking only one index

```
Auth::user()->friends()->where('status', 'received')->first()
```

or you can use the array, but make sure to use => operator

```
Auth::user()->friends()->where(['status' => 'received'])->first()
```